# MVC pattern not specific to JDBC, in regards to three tier architecture

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller

In regards to the MVC-pattern and the three-layer architecture, I'm a bit confused. 
I know the difference between the two, but let's take an example of a java web project. Where we have a JSP-component, Servlet, Java Bean and a connection to a Database.

Is my understanding correct, that in the MVC-pattern, the JSP-page is the view that is presented to the user, the controller is the servlet that handles the request sent to the view, and the model is the objects (for example a java bean), that is sent through the controller to display dynamic content on the JSP-page.

Where is the three-tier architecture both the JSP, and Servlet component is the presentation layer, since that is what is being processed and displayed to the user, whereas the logic-tier is the java beans, where the methods of calculations are being processed, and the data tier, is the database along with the components of the JDBC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three tier is simple, you have a client, a server, and a database.

In the web world its a browser, a server(An example being a java application), and some sort of data store(Like a MySql server).

MVC is a design pattern used within an application that takes data and creates a presentation of that data. You can actually have it within every layer of a three tier architecture but it is most common within the server tier.  In a single page application you may have a MVC in the client code, although, most client side frameworks take different approaches when compared to classic MVC.